# Fourier transform method of solving the heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

We have a heat equation given by:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$

We know that $\mathcal{F}\{ u'' \}=-\xi^2\hat{u}$. Defining $\hat{u}(\xi,t)=\int_{\mathcal{R}}u(x,t)e^{ix\xi}dx$, how come we are allowed to write the following:

$$\frac{d\hat{u}}{dt}=-\xi^2 \hat{u}$$

**Question:** I can understand why when integrating $\int_{\mathcal{R}}u(x,t)e^{ix\xi}dx$ wrt $x$ we get $\xi$ in place of $x$ for the $\hat{u}$, i.e. $\hat{u}(\xi,t)$, but aren't we supposed to integrate $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$ wrt to $t$ (i.e. $\int_{\mathcal{R}}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}e^{it\xi}dt$)? and would not that result in $\frac{d\hat{u}(x,\xi)}{dt}$? which means we cannot write $\frac{d\hat{u}}{dt}=-\xi^2 \hat{u}$? Now that I think about it, I think I have totally mixed up stuff (integrating away the variables).

Comment: What you do to one side of the equation, you must do to the other side as well. You can transform both sides wrt t, or transform both sides wrt x, but you can't have a mix of both.

Comment: ohh. that is why we can write that. Thanks!